# How to create parameter (or bins) for diverging colors on Tableau 8.2 Treemap

Tags: tableau-api, treemap

I am trying to organize the color palette for a Tableau treemap.

First, I don't understand how the diverging palette is organized and why the lower value turns negative when I add steps.

Second, I want to create bins and color code them - like, make all values below a certain amount one color, etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated field and place that in the color pill.

`if [your measure value] >= threshold1 then a
elseif [your measure value] >= threshold2 then b
elsif [your measure value] >= threshold3 then c
else d end`

Repeat this as needed then place it on the color pill. Set colors as desired to a, b, c, d values.

I'm not sure what you mean by your first question. Please give a sample workbook if possible.